# Can additional MyBlock icons be added to the EV3 palette of icons available in the MyBlock builder?

Tags: ev3, software, ev3-g

I'm a big believer in using MyBlocks when using EV3.  For FLL teams, every robot needs to move forward, backward, turn right, turn left, arm up, arm down.  Even before a robot is built, those MyBlocks can be created.  However, none of the icons on the available palette of icons seem suited to the task.

Is there a way to add icons to the palette?

The palette of icons for the parameters is much more useful, so for now, we'll ignore that palette.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the directory

- (for home edition) c:\Program Files (x86)\LEGO Software\LEGO MINDSTORMS EV3 Home Edition\Resources\MyBlocks\images\
- (for edu version) c:\Program Files (x86)\LEGO Software\LEGO MINDSTORMS Edu EV3\Resources\MyBlocks\images\

And create a group of 3 icons for each new icon:

- PolyGroup_NNN_NAME_Diagram.png [size 34x34] - visible in the diagram
- PolyGroup_NNN_NAME_Palette.png [size 25x25] - visible in the command palette
- PolyGroup_NNN_NAME_Palette_MouseOver.png [size 25x25] - visible in the command palette while moving the mouse over the icon

Where

- NNN is a next available number (98 icons already installed), so continue with 098
- NAME - use some name

Restart the SW and open MyBlock builder, you will find the added icon.

It will not work, if you open your code on another EV3 installation without your modifications.