# After adding a MyBlock icon to the EV3 palette of MyBlock icons, how can the new icon be associated to an existing MyBlock?

Tags: mindstorms, ev3, programming, software, ev3-g

After following the advice given in [adding a MyBlock icon to the EV3 palette](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/4737/can-additional-myblock-icons-be-added-to-the-ev3-palette-of-icons-available-in-t), can the icon be associated to an existing MyBlock?

Something better than copy/paste the contents of the existing MyBlock into a new MyBlock.

Comment: follow this: http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/4622/is-it-possible-to-edit-a-my-block-input-parameter-value/4689#4689

Comment: As mentioned in [this answer](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/9278/3498), since v1.3.0, it is possible to edit my blocks.